# Protect my java application from being copied

Tags: java

How do I stop someone from copying and duplicating the application i am making in java ? I am using mysql as back-end for my application and the platform is Linux. Is there a way to provide this security ?

EDIT  :

Is there a way like in windows where some applications even if we copy the folder and past it into other system it wont work. I don't know how they are doing it. Is there any similar thing that I can do here ?

Comment: Do you mean copying the program binary as a whole, or parts of the code into other programs, or re-implementing functionality (cloning the program)?

Comment: "How do I stop someone from copying and duplicating the application i am making in java ?"  Either don't distribute it, or make it so crappy that no-one would bother copying it.  Most people that ask this question take the 2nd route (by incompetence - rather than design).  BTW - unless your 'killer app.' has some functionality that is both revolutionary and non-intuitive, an easy (and quite legal) way to get a copy is to get testers to describe the inputs & outputs, designers to specify that I/O, & coders to implement it.  They will probably come up with a better version than yours.

Comment: @Thilo: I mean the program binary as a whole..

Comment: @Andrew: I mean i want to protect the application from direct copy and paste technique.. I know it is impossible to stop copying. I just want to eliminate the obvious ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, here is an alternate answer to my comment.

1. Don't sell software, sell support.
2. Implement a simple licensing system tied to an email address.
3. Only provide support for users with registered email addresses.

For tips on creating that, see [Software Licensing System](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2172450)  at the OTN.  The solutions shown there are crackable, but not by the casual end user.

Comment: or go cloud, software as a service ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is really *nothing* you can do to stop piracy, as a user must be able to run code on their computer.  Some companies have used hardware tokens, but this is expensive for a small developer.

A small step would be to only deliver the class files, and possibly run them through an obfuscator.

Here in an example obfuscater.

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Here is a good page on securing java code.

http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Research/Students/DouglasLow/obfuscation.html

Comment: is there no other way to enable first level security ? So that the application is protected atleast to basic users(beginners)

Answer (score 1):

Is your project open source? If so, then you'll want to use the [appropriate licensing](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/category). If not, read up on [EULA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license_agreement)s and consult a lawyer.

Comment: no my application is not open source. Licencing is the next stage but i want to enable some kind of security in my application. So is there a way to do it ?/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way we can prevent users to copy the way you have mentioned.

This is the biggest challenge that all the medium sized product based companies are facing and they are spending quite a lot of time on preventing this.

I aggree with @Milhous & @Andrew Thompson replies

Answer (score 1):

There are several commercial Java licensing systems that do exactly what you need (but you should dig into the details as not all of them are actually multiplatform Java, but have just wrapped a C library).

The standard technique for preventing simple replication of an application on other machines is node-locking, where the application checks at runtime that certain system parameters match the encrypted values on its license. The MAC address is commonly used, but this is not a good choice as it can be set by admins on many systems. I'd recommend using a combination of parameters, such as login name, host name, installation directory and so forth.

The licensing process can be manual for low-volume sales, or automated for higher volume licensing. In the automated approach the license is automatically locked to its host during product activation, transparently to the user. As well as being simple and familiar for the user, modern [product activation][2] systems can both meet your goal of preventing copying, and allowing users to relocate their license to another machine if they wish (whether or not their systems have an Internet connection.

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the middle of trying this myself, but maybe you can configure your program to get the mac address of the computer (that you want it to run on) on first-run. Then have it save it to the registry. Then, in your main method have it get your mac address and match it against that of the registry. (The registry tends to put forward slashes where there are spaces but removing the slashes should get you a match).

Comment: This is not an answer.